# Misunderstanding during DATE comparison sql

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2012

I'm using a SQL Server 2012 database and I'm trying to retrieve all employee ids' and there first names who didn't handle an order on February 2 2008 and I ran into such issue

```
Select 
    Distinct E.empid, E.firstname
from 
    HR.Employees E 
where  
   E.empid in (Select empid
               From Sales.Orders As S
               where orderdate <> '20080212')
```

This query returns all employee ids' and first name but this query returns only employ ids' who have handled the order on that day

```
Select Distinct E.empid, E.firstname
    from HR.Employees E 
    where  E.empid in (Select  empid
    From Sales.Orders As S
    where  orderdate  = '20080212')
```

I understand that problem is in filtering `orderdate` but can you tell me guys what am I doing wrong

Comment: Try changing the 2nd query, putting `NOT IN` instead of `IN`.

Comment: did you mean February 12 2008, or did you want to compare with `orderdate = '20080202'?

Comment: I want all dates except  `orderdate = '20080202'. I can't understand why  `orderdate <>'20080202' doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume this is a DataTime column not a Date column. As a DateTime you are asking for employees who didn't take an order at one instant in time not across the whole day.  There are many variants to handle this but the one I would use is

```
Select Distinct E.empid, E.firstname
    from HR.Employees E 
    where  E.empid in (Select  empid
    From Sales.Orders As S
    where  orderdate  >= '20080212'
           and
           orderdate < '20080213')
```

Comment: in this case I'm getting only employees who handled the order and I want completely opposite

Comment: Given that the query with the `=` worked, this is not the problem.

Comment: @automatic: I, too, prefer the `<= and <` comparison with date datatypes but you have a typo: There is no `=>` operator.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with your logic.  No employees only handled orders on that date.  Your first query is getting all employees that had an order on any date but that date.

What you want for the first query is:

```
Select Distinct E.empid, E.firstname
from HR.Employees E 
where  E.empid not in (Select  empid
From Sales.Orders As S
where  orderdate  = '20080212')
```

The subquery in your first query gets all employees who worked on a date other than 2008-02-12.  Presumably, that is all employees.  Well, someone could have started on that day and quit or been fired, but that didn't happen.

What you want is to exclude all employees that worked on that day.  So, you need an "=" in the subquery and then to exclude them with `not in`.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, but can you explain to me my error more accurately  **No employees only handled orders on that date** I don't quite get this part of your response